# Cross network video chat not working

Tags: android, webrtc

I am using webrtc android sample to run video chat between users. I am able to achieve this in same network but when I tried in different networks then its getting failed.

I am using below publicly available STUN/TURN servers to achieve this but still no success and getting unauthorization error in android logcat.

Below is piece of code which I am using:

```
public static List<PeerConnection.IceServer> defaultIceServers(){
    List<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new ArrayList<PeerConnection.IceServer>(25);
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:turn.bistri.com:80", "homeo", "homeo"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("turn:turn.anyfirewall.com:443?transport=tcp", "webrtc", "webrtc"));

    // Extra Defaults - 19 STUN servers + 4 initial = 23 severs (+2 padding) = Array cap 25
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun3.l.google.com:19302"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun4.l.google.com:19302"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:23.21.150.121"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun01.sipphone.com"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.ekiga.net"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.fwdnet.net"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.ideasip.com"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.iptel.org"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.rixtelecom.se"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.schlund.de"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stunserver.org"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.softjoys.com"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.voiparound.com"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.voipbuster.com"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.voipstunt.com"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.voxgratia.org"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.xten.com"));

    return iceServers;
}

public void onConnectedToRoom(final boolean initiator) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (peerConnectionClient == null) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Room is connected, but EGL context is not ready yet.");
                return;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Creating peer connection");
            peerConnectionClient.createPeerConnection(VideoRendererGui.getEGLContext(),
                    localRender, remoteRender, new SignalingParameters(defaultIceServers(), initiator));

            if (initiator) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Creating OFFER...");
                // Create offer. Offer SDP will be sent to answering client in
                // PeerConnectionEvents.onLocalDescription event.
                peerConnectionClient.createOffer();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and getting below errors in android logcat:

```
07-23 21:23:22.000 6967-7293/com.androidhacks7.apprtc_android E/libjingle: (port.cc:371): Jingle:Port[audio:1:0::Net[wlan0:192.168.1.0/24:Unknown]]: Received STUN request with bad local username SkU40kVEtFhhOb5s from 192.168.1.146:52840
07-23 21:23:22.000 6967-7293/com.androidhacks7.apprtc_android I/libjingle: (port.cc:623): Jingle:Port[audio:1:0::Net[wlan0:192.168.1.0/24:Unknown]]: Sending STUN binding error: reason=Unauthorized to 192.168.1.146:52840
07-23 21:23:22.000 6967-7293/com.androidhacks7.apprtc_android E/libjingle: (port.cc:393): Jingle:Port[audio:1:0::Net[wlan0:192.168.1.0/24:Unknown]]: Received STUN binding error: class=4 number=1 reason='Unauthorized' from 192.168.1.146:52840
07-23 21:23:22.048 6967-7293/com.androidhacks7.apprtc_android I/libjingle: (port.cc:1262): Jingle:Conn[0xb87380f0:audio:ViJICO7Z:1:0:local:udp:192.168.1.146:52840->zwMRKbEM:1:1686052607:stun:udp:125.99.173.42:52840|C--W|7241540810645061118|-]: Sent STUN ping, id=69646f336c34554738333256, use_candidate=0
07-23 21:23:22.097 6967-7293/com.androidhacks7.apprtc_android I/libjingle: (port.cc:1262): Jingle:Conn[0xb8173b98:audio:ViJICO7Z:1:0:local:udp:192.168.1.146:52840->4caWssAt:1:1686052607:stun:udp:157.34.21.231:49034|C--I|7241540810645061118|-]: Sent STUN ping, id=4e4130384947677142487556, use_candidate=0
```

Can anybody suggest what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Relevant reading https://andrewjprokop.wordpress.com/2015/01/27/understanding-sip-authentication/

Comment: Basically, it's most probably just challenging your authorization, and doesn't necessarily mean an error has happened.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 

I am using webrtc framework and using socket.io as signalling server and setuped TURN and STUN server as well. Also tried with publicly available STUN servers but still not able to achieve cross network video chat.

I want to confirm if these are publicly available servers then why these are not working?

Did you or anybody else tried these servers?

--
Thanks

Comment: Might wanna try without TURN and STUN servers first, since STUN timeouts can cause the SIP session to be terminated prematurely. Use then only when you sure you need them, and when you need them.